# How do I convert coordinates in WKT format to columns of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, shapely

I have extracted co-ordinates data from Twitter. The points I got are in the WKT format. I want to split them into two columns of Latitude and Longitude.
The format of the coordinates is

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.58168, 12.8952]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.64363, 12.9739]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [75.9372318, 12.44627712]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.5945627, 12.9715987]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.53584257, 13.05144109]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.5945627, 12.9715987]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.58721, 12.96643]}
```

I removed all the punctuations and unwanted text using str.replace

```
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace('type,?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace('Point,?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace('coordinates,?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace('{,?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace(',,?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace(':,?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace('],?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace(',?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace('},?' , '')
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.str.replace("'',?" , "")
```

I tried to split the column using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.coordinates.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),
                             columns = ['Long','Lat'])
```

But it's not working.
Please let me know what can be done to convert WKT to Columns of Co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

The `geopandas` [docs](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) covers importing data in WKT format using `shapely`. In their example, given your dataframe `df`, you could try:

```
from shapely import wkt
import geopandas as gpd

df['coordinates'] = df['coordinates'].apply(wkt.loads)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='coordinates')
```

If you want, you can get the latitude and longtitude and assign back to your original dataframe by doing the following.

```
df['lat'] = gdf.geometry.x
df['long'] = gdf.geometry.y
```

Since you didn't provide a complete minimum working example, I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work.

Comment: The format of the coordinate from the tweet is
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.58168, 12.8952]}
I tried applying your method but it is not working. The error is: ParseException: Unknown type: '{'TYPE':'
I tried removing other text except for POINT, still the problem persists
ParseException: Unknown type: ''POINT''
Please help me with this.

Comment: I think the argument that needs to be passed for point geometries to wkt.loads is a string of the form `'Point (77.58168 12.8952)'`. If I knew what your data looked like I could help you transform it to this format.

Comment: df.[coordinates] = 
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.58168, 12.8952]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.64363, 12.9739]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [75.9372318, 12.44627712]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.5945627, 12.9715987]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.53584257, 13.05144109]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.5945627, 12.9715987]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.58721, 12.96643]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [77.81167482, 13.07899418]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [76.4481516, 9.78418701]}